# Need help in getting the column value in the subquery to the main query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have few tables called, "Sharing", "playlist", "groups", "content",.

Sharing table:

```
playlistID, expirationDate, groupID
```

Groups table:

```
userID ,groupID
```

Playlist table:

```
Playlistid, contentUid
```

Content table:

```
contentID, contentUid
```

Here, I want to get the contentID and the expirationDate for the given userID.

Using 'userId', i got the the list of 'groupID' for that user and checked it with the 'groupID' in the "sharing" table. If the "sharing" table has the 'groupID' , i took those 'playlistID' and using that 'playlisID' i took the 'contentID' but i want to get the 'expirationDate' of  the contentID which is in "sharing" table

Below query returns the contentID, not the expirationDate of the playlist it belongs to as I have used the subquery using 'IN'

Query used:

```
SELECT ContentID 
FROM content
WHERE contentUid IN (SELECT contentuid
                    FROM playlist
                    WHERE playlistuuid IN (SELECT playlistID 
                                           FROM sharing
                                           WHERE groupID IN (SELECT GroupID 
                                                             FROM groups
                                                             WHERE UserID = 605)
                                             AND playlistID IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, a subquery probably isn't the best option. Try joining your tables:

```
SELECT c.ContentUid, s.expirationDate
FROM content c, playlist p , sharing s, groups g
WHERE c.contentUid = p.contentuid
AND p.playlistid = s.playlistID
AND s.groupID = g.groupID
AND g.userID = 605
```

Now you can access anything from the relevant record in any of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.ContentUid, s.expirationDate
FROM content c
JOIN playlist p 
ON c.contentUid = p.contentuid
JOIN sharing s
ON p.playlistid = s.playlistID
JOIN groups g
ON s.groupID = g.groupID
WHERE g.userID = @userID
```